# .Net Application logs out on certain pages

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, session-state

I have a .Net website and when I click the menu for certain pages I am automatically logged out. I tried debugging by opening code and hooking up to the environment database but I am able to open the pages locally. I am not sure why this is the case.

I would like some input about where to start troubleshooting.

Comment: Can you give some typical pages this happens with? Is your site based on a specific starter or template?

Answer (score 0):

I would first check if the server is faulting and losing the session somehow. Perhaps the worker process is crashing or the application pool is recycling for some reason. Without more information this is just a guess though.